# Obtaining the original Java class while using instanceof and casting

Tags: java, exception, casting, instanceof

First off, for anyone out there who abhors, detests and despises the `instanceof` operator, I understand your concerns with it, but am stuck using it. That's because I don't have the authority to completely refactor the way another development team set a project up, so unless I'm missing somethin here, I just don't see any way of avoiding it.

I have a Java POJO that cannot be changed, and allows you to set an `Exception` as one of its properties:

```
public class Message {
    private Exception exception;

    public void setException(Exception exc) {
        this.exception = exc;
    }
}
```

Again, I can't change this `Message` class.

I am writing an error handler method that gets passed a `MessageContainer` instances, and I need logic to do different things depending on what *type* of exception was set on the container's `Message`:

```
public class ErrorHandler {
    public void handle(MessageContainer container) {
        Message msg = container.getMessage();
        Exception exc = msg.getException();

        if(exc instanceof FizzException)
            System.out.println("Do x");
        else if(exc instanceof BuzzException)
            System.out.println("Do y");
        else
            System.out.println("Do z");
    }
}
```

Again, I can't change the fact that `ErrorHandler#handle` is passed a `MessageContainer` and not an injectable `Message` instance.

So, even though I really don't like to use `instanceof`, I don't see any other way of accomplishing this logic (but by all means, please make suggestions...as long as they don't involve making changes to `Message`, `MessageContainer`, or the `handle(MessageContainer)` method!).

But even with using `instanceof`, how does this code even work? Once you pull the `Exception` out of the `Message`, I don't think any of the `instanceof`s will fire, because its cast to an `Exception`, with no way to detect if it's `BuzzException`, `FizzException`, etc. What are my options here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will work as expected. During runtime, `instanceof` statements will compare the actual type of `exc`, and not just assume this is only an `Exception`. If the only statement that worked was `exc instanceof Exception`, `instanceof` would be totally worthless :)

Another solution (which I would avoid to use) would be to compare fully qualified class names:

```
String fqcn = exc.getClass().getName();

if (fqcn.equals("com.foo.FizzException") {
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: the last bit won't work because it will dispatch on the compile-time type, not on the runtime type of the variable.

Comment: +1 for first part -1 for second, it will not work, as Nathan Hughes ^^ says.

Comment: @NathanHughes is right. I just wrote this little test program: http://pastebin.com/TiZJXrXs in all four cases, it calls the method for Object.

Comment: You're right, I forgot this. I removed the last part from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The cast to exception on

```
Exception exc = msg.getException();
```

does not erase the exception runtime type. It has merely cast it to a base type. The `instanceof` will still work. However, if your FizzException extends BuzzException, then you will need to do the `instanceof` checks in the other order. i.e. check for the most derived type first.

Otherwise, it will go into the base class check clause instead of the derived one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want.  If the exceptions are all "given" and you can't change their implementations then you can use exception.getClass().getName() to get the class name and, maybe, look it up in a table or whatever to pick your course of action.

If you *can* change many of the exception implementations have them all implement an interface that provides a "functionality()" method or whatever.  If an given Exception object is `instanceof MyFunctionalityInterface` then cast to MyFunctionalityInterface and call `functionality()` to have it return the info you need to guide your actions.  Then use instanceof or getClass().getName() to manage the Exception classes you can't change.